# Laravel-Vue: hide an icon with vue if the string value is null

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need to hide an icon with vue if the string value is null.
i tried with v-if but it doesn't work.
How can I do?

This is my code:

```
<td class="pl-24">
  <div v-if="$page.tenants.tags.length > 0" class="flex items-center">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
      <path
        d="M9.16667 2.5L16.6667 10C17.0911 10.4745 17.0911 11.1922 16.6667 11.6667L11.6667 16.6667C11.1922 17.0911 10.4745 17.0911 10 16.6667L2.5 9.16667V5.83333C2.5 3.99238 3.99238 2.5 5.83333 2.5H9.16667"
        stroke="#52525B"
        stroke-width="1.25"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
      ></path>
      <circle cx="7.50004" cy="7.49967" r="1.66667" stroke="#52525B" stroke-width="1.25" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
    </svg>
    <p class="text-sm leading-none text-gray-600 ml-2">{{ tenant.tags ? tenant.tags : "" }}</p>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="flex items-center"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: try `v-if="tenants.tags"`

Comment: I think v-if="$page.tenants.tags.length > 0 " is incorrect. Please try it in other ways.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon i tried with v-if="tenants.tags.length > 0" but it does not work...

Comment: @Crown716 can you give me some ideas? thx

Comment: I have a question.  Is that icon shown when  tag.length > 0 ?

Comment: v-if="$page.tenants.tags && $page.tenants.tags.length > 0"